# iOS5 UIAppearance protocol error when using [[UINavigationBar appearance] setOpaque:NO]

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar, appearance

When using the new appearance proxy in iOS5 I receive the following error when trying to set the opaque property `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setOpaque:NO];`

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** Illegal property type, c for appearance setter, setOpaque:'
```

Any suggestions or interpretations of the error are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look into the Developer Library: [UINavigationBar Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006887-CH3-SW16). You can not set the opaqueness of the UIAppearance object of a UINavigationBar. Only those things stated there. Happened to me as well, auto completion shows every possible choice, not just those supported by the control you are trying to modify.

Comment: It was that auto completion that got me as well.